# PHPStorm7: Show line numbers

Tags: phpstorm

I use `MacOSX 10.8.5` and `PHPStorm 7`. I try to set `Show line nubers` globaly, for all projects. I checked `Show line number` in `Preferences > [IDE settings] Editor > Apperance` and all is ok until I turn off application. After restart are old settings.

In `PHPStorm 6.x` everything was ok.

What doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have EditorConfig plugin installed? If yes -- please disable it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115224

Comment: Yes, thx. Line numbers are visible after diable EditorConfig plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please disable **EditorConfig plugin** if you have it installed and enabled. It does not seem to be fully compatible with v7: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115224

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Users follow this steps:

Click on File->Settings->

In the Settings dialog box Expand Editor under IDE Settings.

Click Apperance - > select Show line numbers.

Click Apply->Ok.